# Do concurrent collections cache the enumerator snapshots?

Tags: c#, performance, concurrent-collections

If I understood correctly, then the concurrent collections create a snapshot as a source for the `Enumerator` used in a `foreach` loop, which requires locking.

Do they cache the snapshots or lock every time? Does this have a potential performance impact? I'm sceptical about micro-measurements, because they so easily lead to false conclusions and am trying to understand the inner workings.

Thanks!

Comment: The [reference documentation](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentDictionary.cs,780) for `GetEnumerator` on `ConcurrentDictionary` states that it does not snapshot or lock, and while it's safe to read the data may be mutated while you have it. Which concurrent collections are you referring to specifically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't appear to cache. Here's the code from `ConcurrentBag<T>`:

```
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
{
    if (m_headList != null)
    {
        bool lockTaken = false;
        try
        {
            FreezeBag(ref lockTaken);
            return ToList().GetEnumerator();
        }
        finally
        {
            UnfreezeBag(lockTaken);
        }
    }
    return new List<T>().GetEnumerator();
}

private List<T> ToList()
{
    List<T> list = new List<T>();
    for (ThreadLocalList threadLocalList = m_headList; threadLocalList != null; threadLocalList = threadLocalList.m_nextList)
    {
        for (Node node = threadLocalList.m_head; node != null; node = node.m_next)
        {
            list.Add(node.m_value);
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```